# How to use Wordnet 3.1 with NLTK on Python?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

**Important Edit**

As informed by @Pengin in comments. NLTK is supporting WordNet 3.1 from January 2022. Thus this question is deemed irrelevant now.

---

I need to use Wordnet 3.1 for my research work, but NLTK (python) ships with the default wordnet version: 3.0. *It is important that I use the latest version of Wordnet.*

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet
>>> wordnet.get_version()
'3.0'
```

But, since NLTK 3.1 is the latest version, and I cannot find any way to download and access it using `nltk.download()`, I am searching for a workaround.

As written in Wordnet Website ([current version link here](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/download/current-version)), I am quoting below:

> ### WordNet 3.1 DATABASE FILES ONLY
>
> You can [download the WordNet 3.1 database files](http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/wn3.1.dict.tar.gz). Note that this is not a full package as those above, nor does it contain any code for running WordNet. However, you can replace the files in the database directory of your 3.0 local installation with these files and the WordNet interface will run, returning entries from the 3.1 database. This is simply a compressed tar file of the WordNet 3.1 database files.

I tried downloading the Wordnet 3.1 database files and replaced them with the default Wordnet files at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\corpora` (on Windows system). I doubted that it won't work as the instructions are to replace the database file in the Wordnet software installation, but still, I tried.

On running `wordnet.get_version()`, I am getting the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d64ae1e68b36> in <module>
----> 1 wordnet.get_version()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    118             raise AttributeError("LazyCorpusLoader object has no attribute '__bases__'")
    119 
--> 120         self.__load()
    121         # This looks circular, but its not, since __load() changes our
    122         # __class__ to something new:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py in __load(self)
     86 
     87         # Load the corpus.
---> 88         corpus = self.__reader_cls(root, *self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
     89 
     90         # This is where the magic happens!  Transform ourselves into

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py in __init__(self, root, omw_reader)
   1136 
   1137         # Load the lexnames
-> 1138         for i, line in enumerate(self.open("lexnames")):
   1139             index, lexname, _ = line.split()
   1140             assert int(index) == i

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\api.py in open(self, file)
    206         """
    207         encoding = self.encoding(file)
--> 208         stream = self._root.join(file).open(encoding)
    209         return stream
    210 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py in join(self, fileid)
    335     def join(self, fileid):
    336         _path = os.path.join(self._path, fileid)
--> 337         return FileSystemPathPointer(_path)
    338 
    339     def __repr__(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\compat.py in _decorator(*args, **kwargs)
     39     def _decorator(*args, **kwargs):
     40         args = (args[0], add_py3_data(args[1])) + args[2:]
---> 41         return init_func(*args, **kwargs)
     42 
     43     return wraps(init_func)(_decorator)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py in __init__(self, _path)
    313         _path = os.path.abspath(_path)
    314         if not os.path.exists(_path):
--> 315             raise IOError("No such file or directory: %r" % _path)
    316         self._path = _path
    317 

OSError: No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Punit Singh\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data\\corpora\\wordnet\\lexnames'
```

Then I checked for the file structure and I am listing the before and after tree below.

**File Tree In Wordnet 3.0**

```
wordnet
├── adj.exc
├── adv.exc
├── citation.bib
├── cntlist.rev
├── data.adj
├── data.adv
├── data.noun
├── data.verb
├── index.adj
├── index.adv
├── index.noun
├── index.sense
├── index.verb
├── lexnames
├── LICENSE
├── noun.exc
├── README
├── verb.exc
```

**File Tree In Wordnet 3.1**

```
wordnet
├── adj.exc
├── adv.exc
├── cntlist
├── cntlist.rev
├── cousin.exc
├── data.adj
├── data.adv
├── data.noun
├── data.verb
├── index.adj
├── index.adv
├── index.noun
├── index.sense
├── index.verb
├── log.grind.3.1
├── noun.exc
├── sentidx.vrb
├── dbfiles
    ├── adj.all
    ├── adj.pert
    ├── adj.ppl
    ├── adv.all
    ├── cntlist
    ├── noun.act
    ├── noun.animal
    ├── noun.artifact
    ├── noun.attribute
    ├── noun.body
    ├── noun.cognition
    ├── noun.communication
    ├── noun.event
    ├── noun.feeling
    ├── noun.food
    ├── noun.group
    ├── noun.location
    ├── noun.motive
    ├── noun.object
    ├── noun.person
    ├── noun.phenomenon
    ├── noun.plant
    ├── noun.possession
    ├── noun.process
    ├── noun.quantity
    ├── noun.relation
    ├── noun.shape
    ├── noun.state
    ├── noun.substance
    ├── noun.time
    ├── noun.Tops
    ├── verb.body
    ├── verb.change
    ├── verb.cognition
    ├── verb.communication
    ├── verb.competition
    ├── verb.consumption
    ├── verb.contact
    ├── verb.creation
    ├── verb.emotion
    ├── verb.Framestext
    ├── verb.motion
    ├── verb.perception
    ├── verb.possession
    ├── verb.social
    ├── verb.stative
    ├── verb.weather
```

Any suggestions or solutions on how to use Wordnet 3.1 with NLTK (Python) will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As of Jan 2022, NLTK officially supports WordNet 3.1 by `nltk.download("wordnet31")`

Comment: Thanks for informing me. I'll add it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching and trial and error, I was able to use Wordnet 3.1 on NLTK (Python). I tweaked [this gist](https://gist.github.com/e-mon/28ca194a80450311a342) to make it work. I am providing the details below.

I divided the code provided in the gist in 3 parts.

**Part 1. download_extract.py**

```
import os

nltkdata_wn = '/path/to/nltk_data/corpora/wordnet/'
wn31 = "http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/wn3.1.dict.tar.gz"

if not os.path.exists(nltkdata_wn+'_3.0'):
    os.mkdir(nltkdata_wn+'_3.0')
os.system('mv '+nltkdata_wn+"* "+nltkdata_wn+"_3.0/")

if not os.path.exists('wn3.1.dict.tar.gz'):
    os.system('wget '+wn31)

os.system("tar zxf wn3.1.dict.tar.gz -C "+nltkdata_wn)
os.system("mv "+nltkdata_wn+"dict/* "+nltkdata_wn)
os.rmdir(nltkdata_wn + 'dict')
```

This is used to back up the existing Wordnet 3.0 folder from `wordnet` to `wordnet_3.0`, download the Wordnet 3.1 database, and put it in folder `wordnet`. Since I am on a Windows system, I did this manually.

**Part 2. create_lexnames.py**

```
import os

nltkdata_wn = '/path/to/nltk_data/corpora/wordnet/'
dbfiles = nltkdata_wn+'dbfiles'

with open(nltkdata_wn+'lexnames', 'w') as fout:
    for i,j in enumerate(sorted(os.listdir(dbfiles))):
        pos = j.partition('.')[0]
        if pos == "noun":
            syncat = 1
        elif pos == "verb":
            syncat = 2
        elif pos == "adj":
            syncat = 3
        elif pos == "adv":
            syncat = 4
        elif j == "cntlist":
            syncat = "cntlist"
        fout.write("\t".join([str(i).zfill(2),j,str(syncat)])+"\n")
```

This creates the required `lexnames` file in the `wordnet` folder.

**Part 3. testing_wn31.py**

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

nltkdata_wn = '/path/to/nltk_data/corpora/wordnet/'

# Checking generated lexnames file.
for i, line in enumerate(open(nltkdata_wn + 'lexnames','r')):
    index, lexname, _ = line.split()
    ##print line.split(), int(index), i
    assert int(index) == i

# Testing wordnet function.
print(wn.synsets('dog'))
for i in wn.all_synsets():
    print(i, i.pos(), i.definition())
```

This tested the generated `lexname` file and also tested if the wordnet functions are working fine.

Once I am done with this procedure, I ran following code in python and found that it is actually running version 3.1

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet
>>> wordnet.get_version()
'3.1'
```

**A Word of Caution**

Once you replace the Wordnet 3.1 database, you'll notice that if you run the following code

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

in the download dialog box, you will see that under `Corpora` tab, `Wordnet` will be shown as `out of date`, you should not try to update it as it will either replace the wordnet to version 3.0 or break it.